# What does node(){} mean?

Tags: c++

```
struct node{
   int key, prior, cnt, val;
   node *l, *r;
   node(){}
   node(int nkey) : key(nkey), prior(rand()), cnt(1), l(0), r(0), val(1){}
};
```

What does `node(){}` do ? please explain it, thank you.

Comment: It's the default constructor.

Comment: The title of the post and question in the post are totally different. You should try to re-write the title such that it is directly related to the core question as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does `node(){}` do ? please explain it

`node(){}` looks like [treap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) node. Code `node(){}` is the syntax for defining the default constructor.

Without default constructor, you can't use `node` in stl containers like `std::array`, `std::vector` etc without extra code so you need the definition for default. In coding competitions, people tend to write the minimal code and use the existing functionality as much as possible sometimes even at the cost of leaking scope etc.

Comment: *edit* , ok , if you have other constructor , you need default constructor to use in array ._. , thanks for the explanation .

Comment: I'm glad if it helped you.

Comment: All standard containers are usable without a default constructor. `std::array` does need initialization, but the other ones including `std::vector` can be empty, so there's no issue.

Comment: @Quentin What if a resize is required? For `std::map`, because of `operator []` you must provide default constructor of the value. There are many reasons which can't be all commented upon without seeing more code. I am active in competitive programming and I am used to providing such default constructors at least during short contests to avoid time wastage in fixing compilation error.

Comment: @MohitJain `resize` has an overload which takes the value to initialize new elements with. `std::map`'s `operator[]` is not instantiated until you try to use it -- `at` and `emplace` work fine.

Comment: @Quentin Which means extra code every time I resize. `std::map::operator []` is more convenient at times. Some algorithms may also want default constructor.

Comment: @MohitJain no more code than resizing with default values, then traversing the newly-inserted elements to assign them their *actual* values. My point is, either your class has a sensible default state or it doesn't, standard containers have no relevance to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It defines the the default constructor `node()` as an empty function `{}`.